# Flutter: Use appBar Widget in Floating Action Button instead of the appBar?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout

Here's the widget I'm using in the appBar;

```
 appBar: AppBar(actions: <Widget>[myAppBarIcon()],)
```

And the code for the widget itself;

```
Widget myAppBarIcon() {
   return ValueListenableBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, int newNotificationCounterValue,
        Widget child) {
        return  newNotificationCounterValue == 0? Container(): Stack(
        children: [
          Icon(
            Icons.notifications,
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 30,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 30,
            height: 30,                
            child: Container(
              width: 15,
              height: 15,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Color(0xffc32c37),
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 1)),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                child: Text(
                  newNotificationCounterValue.toString(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
    valueListenable: notificationCounterValueNotifer,
  );
}
```

But I would now like to use the widget in a floating action button instead of the appBar. So here's what I tried;

```
 Scaffold(
      body: FoldableSidebarBuilder(
        drawerBackgroundColor: Colors.black45,
        drawer: CustomDrawer(closeDrawer: (){
          setState(() {
            drawerStatus = FSBStatus.FSB_CLOSE;
          });
        },),
        screenContents: mainStage(),
        status: drawerStatus,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            bottom:140,
            left: 17,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
                mini: true,
                heroTag: null,
                backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
                child: myAppBarIcon()

            ),
          ),         
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

But although no error comes up, myAppBarIcon isn't appearing in the build. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please share the Scaffold/container code where you have this appBar.

Comment: Heres  the scaffold;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it does work. I didn't think so at first till I realized I needed to receive an FCM notification before it appeared. This line was the reason.;

```
return  newNotificationCounterValue == 0? Container()
```

So I'm going to put an empty notification icon in the container.